# EditText displaying as a textview in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hi In My Application if I drag and drop the edit text it displaying it as a `textview`.

Now, If I click the `EditText` I want to select the datepicker option and then select the date Now if i select the edittext nothing happend.

can any one please help me.

**Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <!-- Text Label -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/attend" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Select Class"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    />

    <!-- Spinner Element -->
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"
    />
    <!-- Text Label -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Select Section"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    />

    <!-- Spinner Element -->
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/spinner_section"
    />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxt_fromdate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:hint="@string/from_date">


    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please say acjectly what u want

Comment: hi digvesh if i drag and drop the edittext it showing as a textview

Comment: but in layout that you post i had not seen any textview?

Comment: Try running your UI only..

Comment: can you post your java code

Comment: What do you mean by "drag and drop the edittext"? Where are you moving it to? You want EditText behave as clickable TextView and show DatepickerDialog? Post your Java code.

Comment: post ur java/android code as well

Answer (score 0):

implement setOnClicklistner() to edittext in onclick method put your datepicker dialog code